# CancellationToken in SaveChangesAsync EntityFramework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

How does EF (not EFCore) handle the `cancellationToken` in `dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken)`?

I mean, let's assume I have some Inserts, Updates, and Deletes there which I am applying to DB by `SaveChangesAsync`.

Now it can be a long operation, so when the `cancellationToken` is canceled during the actual query running, what happens? Is it rollbacked?

I am using SQL server.

Comment: `SaveChanges` uses a transaction internally. Any exception thrown while the transaction is active, including due to cancellations, will roll back the transaction. BUT why would this take a long time? A DbContext is a Unit-of-Work meant to track and persist a set of objects needed for a specific scenario. It's not meant for eg ETL scripts

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks! that's what I though, but wasn't sure. 
By a long time I meant like couple of hundred milliseconds, but my point was like if there was a multiple updates, and cancellation token gets cancelled in the middle of updates, I want all od them to be rollbacked, so I don't end up in incosistent state.